# Find a specific keyword of an item in a list

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Say for example I have a list as follows:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

which contains:

```
item1
item 2
testing 123
```

How could I say:

```
"where list item contains the value "123" return that item in full"
```

hence the output result would be:

```
testing 123
```

Comment: You should specify what the return should be if you have more than one value that matches your criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = myList.Where(p => p.Contains("123")).SingleOrDefault();
```

or

```
string s = myList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Contains("123"));
```

Comment: This will fail if there is more than one item with 123

Comment: right but I understand the question as Jamie is searching for only one item.

Comment: So if there are two SingleOrDefault() will throw an exception.

Comment: that is right, if there is more than one item matching this criteria it will throw an exception; which is the proper behaviour I think.

Comment: It is only proper if you don't have multiple items which match, otherwise it fails.  I'm sure the OP won't know to implement the exception handling.  I also expect the OP will at some point have multiples and have to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>()
{
    "item1",
    "item 2",
    "testing 123",
};

var contains123 = myList.Where(x => x.Contains("123"));
```

Comment: This will return more than one item as a result

Comment: @Hogan - The OP didn't specifically say they wanted to return a single item. The way it was phrased there could be zero or more results. That's the way I took it at least.

Comment: OK, it looked to me like he only specified one string as the result.  It said "return that item in full" -- sounds like a singular to me.

Comment: @Hogan - The full line was "where list item contains the value "123" return that item in full". And that sounds like a list predicate to me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on

```
        var list = new List<string>
            {
                "item1",
                "item 2",
                "testing 123"
            };
        var result = list.Find(x => x.Contains("123"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = myList.Select(item => item.Contains("123")).FirstOrDefault();

if (result != null)
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using LINQ.

Example:

```
myList.Single(x => x == "testing 123");
```

if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, This would not work if I specified "123" as the search criteria as specified in my example

Comment: You could use the LINQ Contains() method in that case, but it may require stricter validation on the result set

Comment: Then as the others suggested you can use "Contains(yourValue);"